# Extending TF Lite GPU delegate with missing operations

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

My model uses more operations than TF Lite GPU delegates supports (https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/gpu_advanced#supported_ops).

How can I extend this delegate to add missing operations?

If I got the code it would be probably possible (compile extended TF) but I don't know how to get the code of this experimental branch.

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/gpu#android describes only usage of their ready package.

Comment: Look at [this fork](https://github.com/freedomtan/tensorflow/tree/export_new_nnapi_deleate_to_java_api)